# Objective-C - Playing sound with NSSound - Not working on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: objective-c, linux, ubuntu, nssound

Ok I have GNUStep installed on both a Windows 7 machine, and an Ubuntu Linux machine. Using the EXACT same code, playing sound works under GNUStep on windows, and does absolutely nothing on Linux. I have scoured google, stackoverflow, etc and found NOTHING. I hate that I have to use NSSound on anything but Mac, but I don't have a choice. Has ANYONE got NSSound to work with Linux??

```
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Narnia" ofType:@"wav"];
sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:resourcePath byReference:NO]

[sound play]
```

- Restricted-Extras are installed on linux
- '$aplay Narnia.wav' plays just fine
- The application can't even get info about the wav file like its
  duration when I open it, unlike in windows

Comment: Not to be an a-hole, but are you sure the sound exists on your ubuntu box?

Comment: That's not being an a-hole :) YES, positive. That was the first thing I checked. Sound works in every other app and in system settings.

Comment: Doesn't it work in other GNUstep apps?

Comment: Is this issue unique to this one sound or is it happening for every time you use NSSound on your Ubuntu machine? If it's unique to this sound then I want to say it has to do with encoding, but if it's for all sounds then I think the issue is pretty clear.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? In other apps coded in objective-c via GNUStep? If that's the question, no idea.

Comment: @jraede EVERY sound. EDIT: Sorry I misread the question. It is not unique to every sound, just sounds I am trying to call using the code above. Hope that's clear

Comment: Then it's probably that they're encoded/formatted in a way that Linux/Ubuntu can't play them. Having developed sounds for my iOS game I know that Apple devices are very picky about sound encoding, and Ubuntu probably just doesn't play nicely with whatever format you're using.

Comment: I've used different sounds. .wav and .mp3

Comment: Do you have the MP3 codecs installed? They are typically not by default on Ubuntu.

Comment: What code are you using to play sounds successfully?

Comment: the Same Code Listed In The Question